# How to make a scroll move along with a dialog in a expanding div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

What I am trying to do is to create floating dialogs and then allow the user to put them in any layout they want.

I have a menu div at the top fixed and then a content div that should allow the users to position the dialogs to their convenience, for this I am increasing the size of the content div in case the users want to move some dialogs outside the current visible area, but this is not working correctly.

When a dialog is moved outside the visible part the scrollbars don't follow the dialog, also the increase in the size works only once, to make the div bigger I have to drag it a second time.

If I move the scrollbars with the wheel mouse I can see that the drag doesn't move up to the new div size, but is stuck with the old one.

TLDR: http://jsfiddle.net/peMGg/87/

```
$(".dialog").dialog({
    modal: false,
    open: function () {
        $(this).dialog("widget").appendTo("#content");
    },
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var dlg = $(this).dialog("widget");
        var wDlg = dlg.width();
        var hDlg = dlg.height();
        var xDlg = dlg.position().left
        var yDlg = dlg.position().top;

        var wBody = $("#content").width();
        var hBody = $("#content").height();

        if(wBody - (xDlg + wDlg) < 20) {
            $("#content").width(wBody + 30);
        }
        if(hBody - (yDlg + hDlg) < 20) {
            $("#content").height(hBody + 30);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want this
http://jsfiddle.net/peMGg/102/ 
Because dialog max movement depends on height and width of the body you should make it unlimited before make it dragable, this can be done by another function on mouse press and release...
I first make it undragable on open so we can add function to dialog title bar:

```
open: function () {
    $(this).dialog("widget").appendTo("#content");
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "option", "draggable", false );
},
```

I have added these:

```
var wBodyy = $("body").width();
var hBodyy = $("body").height();
```

at the base so it can be accessible by global,
and then added these functions to store the body width and height then make it 20000 and then make it dragable so it can be dragged! and after begin released it must be again undragable!:

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").mousedown(function() {
    wBodyy = $("body").width();
    hBodyy = $("body").height();
    $("body").width(20000);
    $("body").height(20000);
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "option", "draggable", true );
});
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").mouseup(function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "option", "draggable", false );
});
```

And last I should put original body amount back while dragging as it doesn't check for body anymore! I can put it on dragStart event:

```
dragStart: function(event, ui) {
    $("body").width(wBodyy);
    $("body").height(hBodyy);
},
```

Also to make it bugless when the mouse get out here is a solution:
make mousedown event like this:

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").mousedown(function() {
    if ($("body").width()!=20000){
        wBodyy = $("body").width();
        $("body").width(20000);}
    if ($("body").height()!=20000){
        hBodyy = $("body").height();
        $("body").height(20000);}
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "option", "draggable", true );
});
```

So it change the variable only when needed!
and also on mouse out and drag start must be change to:

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").mouseup(function() {
        if ($("body").width()==20000){$("body").width(wBodyy);}
        if ($("body").height()==20000){$("body").height(hBodyy);}
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "option", "draggable", false );
});
```

and

```
dragStart: function(event, ui) {
    if ($("body").width()==20000){$("body").width(wBodyy);}
    if ($("body").height()==20000){$("body").height(hBodyy);}
},
```

so they will get change on nescesary
Hope it helps

Comment: this does more or less what I want, just sometimes the body doesn't recover its original size if the mouse is released somewhere outside the frame ?, but this might be a artifact of the fiddle. I guess there is no easy and reliable way of doing this, maybe I will have to solve this differently. Thanks.

Comment: Hey nice, the new one is much better and solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have doubt in your question,

IF the `.dialog` box is important or the background `#content`?

I have updated [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/peMGg/90/), if the .dialog box is important,

else please post the problem again, I have made the scroll bar invisible by making `overflow:visible` so that is one trick that should work.

I am working on background `#content` will post new fiddle after some time.

If anything please revert back.

Edit: Updated Fiddle

Updated [`fiddle2`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/pWtFA/1/) when you load the `#content` will grow till the end of `.dialog`

I think that should do :)

Comment: Hi there, I am not seeing to much difference with the one I had.

Comment: Pick the dialog and try to move it outside the window, bottom or right the idea is that the dialog keeps moving and the content div keeps getting bigger and bigger ad infinitum :p this doesn't happens.

Comment: so you want to limit the expanding? I have asked for clarification for that only :) I hope you have seen both fiddles both are different if you can not see much difference :P

Comment: nop, I want exactly the opposite, no limit in the expanding at all, just constantly increasing the content div but for some reason this is not possible if you drag the dialog only once, once it is dropped and dragged again then it will increase a little more etc...

Comment: Oh I see the difference :p load sizes are not important, what I want is to drag the dialog to increase the #content div without any limit of any kind.

Comment: ok, I got your point now! :)  as we have +30 in drag event; it will increase by +30 only else we need to have iterator..! I will try something if It works out :P

Comment: I found out that the Drag Function's behavior is our problem, its better that we design drag function for our purpose that will do better.. as the drag beyond body and scroll bar is a requirement of drag in most of cases. and that we want to avoid, although there should have option to override drag: but I was not able to find working one.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the overflow property needs a bit of actual overflow to let itself do it's job. When you re-size on the fly the `#content` DIV bigger than the actual content, the overflow property can no longer do it's job. By adding a `max-width` and a `max-height` to `#content` you're able to achieve the effect I think you're going for, or at least it should lead you down the right path.

http://jsfiddle.net/howlx5/Z6eHT/